# Change background color of some words in div as user writes something in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I am sorry if this question has been asked millions of times but i really tried hard to find solution for my problem.

Well i am working on a typing-speed script using jquery and php. The script is working good for calculating wpm nwpm etc but the problem is when user types there is no indicator that at which word the user it (Not the char, the WORD, each saperated by a space ).

Let i make it more clear.

I have a div which contains given paragraph

```
<div id="paragraph">Some text to type. It will going to be a long set of words</div>
```

and a textarea to input.
All i want is just to highlight the word which is being typed by the user. Not the char. Like in above paragraph when user starts typing first word "Some" the same word position has to be highlighted and if user pressed space to write the second value that exact style should be given to that word.

So whenever the user hits space the highlight style should be applied to that word. if user hits Som than the highlight word should be "text" which is in that time being typed. 
document.getElementById('paragraph').length gives no solution.

Thanks
Sorry for my bad english and something got confusing..

Comment: where will the user type the word really?

Comment: @Anonymous in the textarea input.

Comment: OP, take a look at fuzzy searching.

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox if i have any idea about that fuzzy thing, i would have thought of it. But still thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help.  It uses a simple string split behavior to highlight the current word that should be typed.  You can change to regex if you have to support double spacing, but that should be trivial.

Working [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pjtzdorL/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="paragraph">Some text to type. It will going to be a long set of words</div>
<textarea id="typingarea" cols="50"></textarea>
```

**Javascript**

```
var paragraphArray = $("#paragraph").text().split(' ');
updateTypewriter();

$("#typingarea").on("keyup", function(){
   updateTypewriter();
});

function updateTypewriter(){
   var typingAreaArray = $("#typingarea").val().split(' ');
   var newTypewriterHtml = "";
   var typingAreaWordIndex = 0;
   paragraphArray.forEach(function(word) {
      if (newTypewriterHtml != ""){
         newTypewriterHtml += " ";
      }
      if (typingAreaWordIndex+1 == typingAreaArray.length){
         newTypewriterHtml += "<span style='background-color: red; font-weight: bold;'>" + word + "</span>";
      } else {
         newTypewriterHtml += word;
      }
      typingAreaWordIndex++;
   });
   $("#paragraph").html(newTypewriterHtml);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rickburns , It worked. There is some conflict but that was in my script i have solved it.